# SQL if condition not met then fail the query

Tags: sql, if-statement, select, hdfs, failover

So I am trying to figure out how to fail a SQL statement incase the case - when statement is not met.

I have been doing some searching and didn't find anything useful
this is the query for example ..

```
select
case when 1 = 1 then 'ok'
else < what to write here?>
end
```

If I am writing a typo or something like that this will fail the query entirely for syntax even if the condition is met .

Hope I could use your help !

Comment: SQL doesn't work like that -- it's declarative rather than imperative. You could add a `WHERE thing IN (1, 2, ...)` to your query to make sure that you only have valid values, and could do something like `IF EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM wherever WHERE value < 0) THEN BEGIN RAISERROR(...) END` as a separate statement.

Comment: I am using Hive, and he is not familiar with BEGIN RAISERROR .. do you know of any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Hive SQL, you can use the `assert_true()` function in order to raise an error if a condition is met.

[You can find it in the Hive docs here.](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/languagemanual+udf#LanguageManualUDF-ConditionalFunctions)

Some examples:

```
jdbc:hive2://> select assert_true(true);
jdbc:hive2://> select assert_true(false);  // returns exception
jdbc:hive2://> select assert_true(1==2);  // returns exception
```